# Como navegar entre pestañas del menu en PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Quisiera saber si me podrían apoyar con la siguiente duda.

Tengo la siguiente ventana principal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que el contenido del mainwindow cambie segun me vaya moviendo en las pestañas.

Es decir la pestaña inicio mostrara en el mainwindow solo un logo.

Mientras que por ejemplo: 
La pestaña de ventas ahora mostrara en el mainwindow todas las opciones que tien por lo general un punto de venta.

espero darme a entender y que puedan orientarme con esto

Comment: No te entendi, explicate mejor, ¿quieres decir cuando presionas "Ventas" quieres que se muestre cierto contenido, cuando se presione "Busqueda" se muestre otro? o quieres que cuando se presione el submenu "Por Nombre" lo haga?

Comment: @eyllanesc . Que se muestre diferente contenido al presionar por ejemplo busqueda. Uno diferente al presionar inicio. Etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mostrar diferentes widgets en un mismo espacio la mejor opción es usar QStackeWidget, este permite intercambiar los widgets.

Por otro lado ese cambio debe hacerse usando la señal 
aboutToShow de los QMenu ya que este se dispara cuando se presiona.

En la siguiente parte muestro un ejemplo simple.

---

```
from functools import partial

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        menubar = self.menuBar()

        menu1 = menubar.addMenu("Menu1")
        for i in range(3):
            menu1.addAction("action{}".format(i))

        menu2 = menubar.addMenu("Menu2")
        for i in range(3):
            menu2.addAction("action{}".format(i))

        self.stacked = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stacked)

        self.stacked.addWidget(Widget1())
        self.stacked.addWidget(Widget2())

        menu1.aboutToShow.connect(partial(self.stacked.setCurrentIndex, 0))
        menu2.aboutToShow.connect(partial(self.stacked.setCurrentIndex, 1))


class Widget1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Primera\nVentana"))


class Widget2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Segunda\nVentana"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\pos.py", line 46, in <module>
    w = MainWindow()
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\pos.py", line 24, in __init__
    menu1.aboutToShow.connect(partial(self.stacked.setCurrentIndex, 0))
NameError: name 'partial' is not defined
[Finished in 0.3s]

Comment: @ellyanesc, si es el mismo codigo que pusiste

Comment: @ellyanesc, parece que era un problema con mi editor de codigo disculpa

Comment: @Revsky01 jajaaj suele suceder, dime que IDE usas para no usarlo nunca, :) ¿te funciono mi codigo?

Comment: @ellyansec, si funciono ocupe el sublimetext pero como lo tengo con crack posiblemente por eso de bugeo jaja

Comment: @Revsky01 Si mi respuesta te ayudo no olvides marcarla como correcta, ¿que ventaja tiene sublime con crack?, yo uso sublime :)

Comment: @ellyanesc, no te muestra el mensaje de que lo compres jaja

Comment: @Revsky01 solo eso, mmm... :(

Comment: disculpa has trabajo firebase con python

Comment: ¿que deseas????

Comment: donde puedo mandarte un email para poder explicarte mejor solo son 2 dudas que tengo pero necesito que veas una imagen para que me explique mejor

Comment: Solo por este medio

Comment: publico la duda y te mando el link de la publicación

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79941/discussion-between-revsky01-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: este es el link https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178945/consultas-con-firebase-y-python y ya como duda final, para ejecutar el script de la lectora de codigo como lo yamo para que se ejecute cuando la lectora detecte un nuevo codigo ?

Comment: explicate mejor sobre lo ultimo, entenderas que no estoy siguiendo todas mis respuestas