# Consultas con firebase y python

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Esta es mi base de datos en firebase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la ruta `/Usuarios/Administradores/Angel,{'Nombre':'Angel'}` la cree directamente dentro de firebase.

Sin embargo las otras 3 las cree desde el siguiente codigo:

```
from firebase import firebase


#s = "hola que hace"
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://new1-3b819.firebaseio.com/')

#result = firebase.post('/Usuarios/Administradores',{'Angel2':{'Nombre':s}})
result = firebase.get('/Usuarios/Administradores/Angel2','Nombre')
print(result)
```

las duas son las siguientes:

1.- Por que firebase genera variables aleatorias a mis otros campos (-LGzdj....) y como puedo evitar que lo haga, para que mis datos se guarden como la ruta que hize dentro de firebase.

2.- Al tratar de recuperar los datos con:

`result = firebase.get('/Usuarios/Administradores/Angel','Nombre')`

Imprime el resultado, pero al cambiarlo a por ejemplo Angel2 o Angel1 solo imprime NONE

Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: @eyllanesc, esta es la duda que tengo con respecto a firebase espero puedas apoyarme

Comment: no pareces estar usando el SDK oficial de firebase. Que librería estas usando ?

Comment: @NeryOrtez, es un sdk de python en github

Comment: Si, encontré el repositorio, después de revisar el código en github, encontré lo que necesitas. Avisame si mi respuesta no te cumple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TL;DR Usa `put(url, key, data)`

---

Lo que está diciendo es que si usas `push` va a 'empujar' la data en el nodo, como si ese nodo fuera una lista. De esa manera podés empujar un montón de datos en un solo nodo, en donde no te importa el ID de cada dato.

Con `put` es como hacer un `set`. Lo que sea que esté escrito en la dirección va a ser reemplazado por la data que enviés.

```
firebase.put('/Usuarios/Administradores', 'User3', {'Nombre': 'Nery', 'Descripcion':'El mas mero macizo'})
```