# StackedWidget, no logra mostrar interfaz.ui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Se me presenta un problema, trato de usar un stackedwidget para que cambie el contenido de mi ventana principal pero no el de la barra de tareas.

este es mi codigo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QMenu
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QPoint
from PyQt5 import uic
from functools import partial



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("1.ui",self)



        self.stacked = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stacked)


        self.stacked.addWidget(Widget1())
        #self.stacked.addWidget(Widget2())

        self.Inicio.clicked.connect(partial(self.stacked.setCurrentIndex,0))

class Widget1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Primera\nVentana"))


App = QApplication([])
Main = MainWindow()
Main.show()
App.exec_()
```

este es el archivo.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>884</width>
    <height>579</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Exe - Ventas</string>
  </property>
  <property name="windowIcon">
   <iconset>
    <normaloff>exe.png</normaloff>exe.png</iconset>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>5000</width>
      <height>27</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">border-top:1px solid black;

background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.384, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 127), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 153));</string>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
    </property>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="Inicio">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>2</x>
       <y>2</y>
       <width>75</width>
       <height>23</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QPushButton#Inicio{
border:0px;
border-right:2px solid #00cc00;
background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

QPushButton#Inicio:hover{

border-right:2px solid blue;
background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 93), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 153));
}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Inicio</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="Ventas">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>2</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton#Ventas{
border:0px;
border-right:2px solid #00cc00;


}

QPushButton#Ventas:hover{

border-right:2px solid blue;
background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 93), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 153));
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Ventas</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="Consulta">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>240</x>
      <y>2</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton#Consulta{
border:0px;
border-right:2px solid #00cc00;


}

QPushButton#Consulta:hover{

border-right:2px solid blue;
background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 93), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 153));
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Consulta</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="Mensajeria">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>320</x>
      <y>2</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton#Mensajeria{
border:0px;
border-right:2px solid #00cc00;


}

QPushButton#Mensajeria:hover{

border-right:2px solid blue;
background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 93), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 153));
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Mensajeria</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="Registro">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>160</x>
      <y>2</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton#Registro{
border:0px;
border-right:2px solid #00cc00;


}

QPushButton#Registro:hover{

border-right:2px solid blue;
background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 93), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 153));
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Registro</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="Salir">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>400</x>
      <y>2</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton#Salir{
border:0px;
border-right:2px solid #00cc00;


}

QPushButton#Salir:hover{

border-right:2px solid blue;
background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 93), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 153));
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Salir</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>311</width>
      <height>181</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background:red;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**este es el resultado sin la implementación del stackedWidget este es el resultado que espero obtener pero utilizando el stacked** para solo modificar lo que aparece debajo de la barra de herramientas que cree

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el resultado que obtengo implantando el stackedwidget:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En mi [respuesta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/178897/22539) he asumido que Inicio, Ventas, etc eran parte del QMenuBar, en tu caso no lo estas usando por lo que la estrategia debe ser modificada.

En primer lugar debes usar layouts para establecer elementos ya que estos manejan la posicion y el tamaño, en tu caso modifique tu .ui

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se observa he establecido los botones dentro del QFrame a traves de QHBoxLayout, y tambien he establecido el QFrame junto con el QStackedWidget a traves de QVBoxlayout, y ese QVBoxLayout es parte del centralwidget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="topframe">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">QFrame#topframe{
    background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.384, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 127), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 15))
}

QFrame#topframe &gt; QPushButton {
    border:0px;
    border-right:2px solid #00cc00;
}

QFrame#topframe &gt; QPushButton:hover {
    border-right:2px solid blue;
    background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 93), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 153));
}</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>2</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
        <number>2</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
        <number>2</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="Inicio">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true"/>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Inicio</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="Ventas">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Ventas</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="Registro">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Registro</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="Consulta">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Consulta</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="Mensajeria">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Mensajeria</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="Salir">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Salir</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>275</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Ahora ya es sencillo añadir los widgets:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic

from functools import partial


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi("1.ui",self)

        d = {self.Inicio: InicioWidget(), self.Ventas: VentasWidget()}

        for button, window in d.items():
            self.stackedWidget.addWidget(window)
            button.clicked.connect(partial(self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget, window))


class InicioWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(InicioWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Inicio\nVentana"))

class VentasWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VentasWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Ventas\nVentana"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note: He modificado los qss añadiendole reglas.

Comment: funciona bien el codigo, pero noto que no puedo agregar otro widget a las clases posteriores. self.lable = QLabel() no funciona¿?, y el layout no agrega solo los widgets en forma vertical¿?

Comment: @Revsky01 si as QLabel no le pasas un padre no se mostrara nunca, no se en que parte agregas el QLabel asi que no se como ayudarte, por otro lado el layout es una manejador de posiciones y tamaño de los widgets, existen el QVBoxLayout que coloca a los widgets verticalmente, QHBoxLayout en forma horizontal, QGridLayout en forma de cuadricula como una matriz, y tambien puedes crear tus propios layouts: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-layouts.html. Te recomiendo a aprender a usarlos para que tengas un buen diseño.

Comment: @Revsky01 si abres el .ui con Qt Designer veras que los botones estan establecidos mediante un QHBoxLayout y para que esten todos a las derechas he usado un SpacerItem, en cambio tu para generar el mismo efecto hiciste que el ancho del QFrame sea lo mas grande posible que puede funcionar pero no es elegante

Comment: @Revsky01 segun lo que entiendo tu deseas tener como paginas, asi que veo la necesidad de añadir mas elementos al QMainWindow, debes crear otros XXXWidgets y añadirlos como lo he hecho con InicioWidget y VentasWidget

Comment: si te agradezco mucho la ayuda, aun continuo aprendiendo mucho y gracias a sus respuestas voy mejorando mucho espero poder seguir contando con tu ayuda GRACIAS

Comment: @Revsky01 te recomiendo revisar la documentación, alli esta todo, y seguir tutoriales ya que sino va a tener muchos problemas como hasta ahora.